# Why is my block only saving the previous state and not the current one?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've made a block for the new wordpress editor and I'm stucked. Everything works fine, except when I save my page. What get posted is the block but in a previous state.

Ex: if I focus on an editable zone add a word and press publish, the latest addition won't be in the payload. Although I can totally see it when I'm logging the components attributes. If I press publish a second time, it will work fine.

Seems to me theres some kind of race condition or some state management I'm doing wrong. I'm totally new to React and Gutenberg.

Here is my save function:

```js
import { RichText } from '@wordpress/editor';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const { align, figures } = attributes;

    const className = classnames({ [ `has-text-align-${ align }` ]: align });

    return (
        <ul className={ className }>
            { figures.map( (figure, idx) => (
                <li key={ idx }>
                    <RichText.Content tagName="h6" value={ figure.number } />
                    <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={ figure.description } />
                </li>
            ) ) }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

and my edit:

```js
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';
import { AlignmentToolbar, BlockControls, RichText } from '@wordpress/editor';
import { Toolbar } from '@wordpress/components';

import classnames from 'classnames';

import { normalizeEmptyRichText } from '../../utils/StringUtils';
import removeIcon from './remove-icon';

const MIN_FIGURES = 1;
const MAX_FIGURES = 4;

export default class FigureEdit extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);

        this.state = {};
        for(let idx = 0; idx < MAX_FIGURES; idx++){
            this.state[`figures[${idx}].number`] = '';
            this.state[`figures[${idx}].description`] = '';
        }
    }

    onNumberChange(idx, number) {
        const { attributes: { figures: figures }, setAttributes } = this.props;
        figures[idx].number = normalizeEmptyRichText(number);
        this.setState({ [`figures[${idx}].number`]: normalizeEmptyRichText(number) });
        return setAttributes({ figures });
    }

    onDescriptionChange(idx, description) {
        const { attributes: { figures: figures }, setAttributes } = this.props;
        figures[idx].description = normalizeEmptyRichText(description);
        this.setState({ [`figures[${idx}].description`]: normalizeEmptyRichText(description) });
        return setAttributes({ figures });
    }

    addFigure() {
        let figures = [...this.props.attributes.figures, {number:'', description:''}];
        this.props.setAttributes({figures});
    }

    removeFigure() {
        let figures = [...this.props.attributes.figures];
        figures.pop();
        this.resetFigureState(figures.length);
        this.props.setAttributes({figures});
    }

    resetFigureState(idx) {
        this.setState({
            [`figures[${idx}].number`]: '',
            [`figures[${idx}].description`]: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {attributes, setAttributes, className} = this.props;
        const { align, figures } = attributes;

        const toolbarControls = [
            {
                icon: 'insert',
                title: 'Add a figure',
                isDisabled: this.props.attributes.figures.length >= MAX_FIGURES,
                onClick: () => this.addFigure()
            },
            {
                icon: removeIcon,
                title: 'Remove a figure',
                isDisabled: this.props.attributes.figures.length <= MIN_FIGURES,
                onClick: () => this.removeFigure()
            }
        ];

        return (
            <>
                <BlockControls>
                    <Toolbar controls={ toolbarControls } />
                    <AlignmentToolbar
                        value={ align }
                        onChange={ align=>setAttributes({align}) }
                    />
                </BlockControls>
                <ul className={ classnames(className, { [ `has-text-align-${ align }` ]: align }) }>
                    { figures.map( (figure, idx) => (
                        <li key={ idx }>
                            <RichText
                                className="figure-number"
                                formattingControls={ [ 'link' ] }
                                value={ figure.number }
                                onChange={ number => this.onNumberChange(idx, number) }
                                placeholder={ !this.state[`figures[${idx}].number`].length ? '33%' : '' }
                            />
                            <RichText
                                className="figure-description"
                                formattingControls={ [ 'link' ] }
                                value={ figure.description }
                                onChange={ description => this.onDescriptionChange(idx, description) }
                                placeholder={ !this.state[`figures[${idx}].description`].length ? 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor' : '' }
                            />
                        </li>
                    ) ) }
                </ul>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there's also this dirty hack I've done on the placeholder which I think is related. My placeholders where overlapping my values until I blurred out of the component.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so it's enqueuing an update, not writing to state immediately. You will have to either use the callback arg on `setState` or use a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: This does not really explain why my state isn't up to date when I publish. There's a gap of dozens of seconds between the input and the submission. SetState even if it's asynchronous should be done in a few ticks.

Comment: `setState` doesn't magically update your initialized values based off an elapsed time. You could let it sit there for days and submit, it still wouldn't have your "updated" state values.

Comment: The issue is that `setState` is async, so that’s why you’d need to use the callback function arg to get the latest value set in state to begin with. My suggestion would be to find the appropriate lifecycle method to put that logic in, if the `setState` callback func arg doesn’t handle your use case

Comment: So what does trigger a state update ? Also I may be misunderstanding how Gutenberg work, but save only use 'attributes' not the state.

Comment: No idea about the wordpress stuff, as I have never used it. I'm not sure what you mean by `So what does trigger a state update?` State changes when changes to `props` occur or directly from `setState`. This will trigger a re-render. Try doing what I described in my answer. Your description of your problem is assuredly from not getting the most recent value because `setState` is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to immutability, in my `onChange` method, I was mutating the `figures` attribute. It seems that you must not do that. You have to give a new object if you want the props to be correctly refreshed.

My change handler now looks something like this:

```js
onChange(idx, field, value) {
    const figures = this.props.attributes.figures.slice();
    figures[idx][field] = normalizeEmptyRichText(value);
    return this.props.setAttributes({ figures });
}
```

As I suspected this also fixed the placeholder issue. With the placeholder now working as expected I can remove all the state and constructor code. Which confirm this had nothing to do with `setState`.